problem with wired connection in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS desktop tune share more_vert
I have installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS desktop on my computer and it has problems with the internet connection.
Initially it was sending a notification repeatedly about a connection failure, after doing some basic configuration the notification of the failure no longer appears but a question mark appears on the network icon and I still do not have an internet connection.
Can you help me, I don't know what to do anymore. The connection is by cable.
Thank you

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager.  Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.

After performing some basic configurations with netplan, as a last option I changed the cable and the problem was solved.
